# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, stack-overflow

Error received:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at AVL.insert(AVL.java:45)
```

I am not familiar with the error I was given, but I do know that it only happens when the array being used to build the AVL tree is a vary large size and is occurring during insert when moving to the right side of the tree. I am not sure why this is happening though (in other words I do not know exactly what StackOverflowError is and why it is happening).

AVL class:

```
//AVL.java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class AVL{
    AvlNode root;

   public void tree(int[] list){
      for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){
         insertPrep(list[i]);
      }
   }

   public void insertPrep(int data){
      if (root==null){root = new AvlNode(data);}
        else {
         AvlNode newNode = new AvlNode(data);
         root = insert(root, newNode);
         root = rebalance(root);
         adjustHeight(root);
      }
    }

   public AvlNode insert(AvlNode node, AvlNode newNode){
      if (node.key > newNode.key){
         if(node.left!=null){node.left=insert(node.left , newNode);}
         else{node.left=newNode;}
      }
      else if (node.key < newNode.key){
         if(node.right!=null){node.right=insert(node.right, newNode);}
         else{node.right=newNode;}
      }
      AvlNode result = rebalance(node); 
      adjustHeight(result);
      return result;
   }

   public int height (AvlNode node ){
      if (node == null){return 0;}
      else {return node.height;}
   }

   public void adjustHeight (AvlNode node){
      if (root != null){ root.height = 1+ Math.max(height(root.left),height(root.right));}
   }

   public AvlNode rebalance (AvlNode node){
      AvlNode newAvlNode = node;

      if (node.left != null && node.right != null){
        if (node.left.height-node.right.height==2){
            if (node.left.left.height>node.left.right.height){
                AvlNode n2 = node.left;
                AvlNode n3 = node;
                n3.left = n2.right;
                n2.right = n3;

                adjustHeight(n3);
                adjustHeight(n2);
                newAvlNode = n2;
            } else {
                AvlNode n1 = node.left;
                AvlNode n2 = node.left.right;
                AvlNode n3 = node;
                n1.right = n2.left;
                n2.left = n1;
                n3.left = n2.right;
                n2.right = n3;

                adjustHeight(n1);
                adjustHeight(n3);
                adjustHeight(n2);
                newAvlNode = n2;
            }
        } else if (node.right.height-node.left.height==2){
            if (node.right.right.height>node.right.left.height){
                AvlNode n1 = node;
                AvlNode n2 = node.right;
                n1.right = n2.left;
                n2.left = n1;

                adjustHeight(n1);
                adjustHeight(n2);
                newAvlNode = n2;
            } else {
                AvlNode n1 = node;
                AvlNode n2 = node.right.left;
                AvlNode n3 = node.right;
                n1.right = n2.left;
                n2.left = n1;
                n3.left = n2.right;
                n2.right = n3;

                adjustHeight(n1);
                adjustHeight(n3);
                adjustHeight(n2);
                newAvlNode = n2;
            }
        }
      }
    return newAvlNode;
   }

   class AvlNode{
    int key, height; //data for input numbers and height for height of nodes to keep balance
    AvlNode left, right; //left for left side of tree and right for right side of tree

      AvlNode(int data){
         key = data;
      }

   }
}
```

Class using AVL:

```
//Tree.java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Tree{

   public static void main(String[] args){

      int n = 30000; //numbers to be in arrays
      int a[] = new int[n]; //first array

      for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
         a[i] = i+1; //insert #'s 1-n; smallest to largest
      }

      //send arrays to be put in AVL trees
      AVL avl = new AVL();
      double timeSoFar = (double)System.nanoTime();
      avl.tree(a);
      double treeTime = (double)System.nanoTime() - timeSoFar;
      printTime('a',treeTime, "AVL");

   }

   public static void printTime(char l, double treeTime, String tree){
      double treeTimeMin = treeTime/600000;
      treeTimeMin/=100000;
      System.out.println("Elapsed time for building " + tree + " " + "Tree for array '" + l + "': " + treeTime + " nanoseconds, or: " + treeTimeMin + " minutes.");
   }

}
```

Comment: Stack overflows usually mean recursion went too far. You most likely have an infinite recursion. To make sure, increase the Java VM stack size tenfold (there's a flag for this, google will know), and see if it still happens

Comment: Can you please identify which line is 45?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this with a debugger?  It would seem to be the most sensible way to find the answer.

Comment: Duplicate of [What is a stack overflow error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stack-overflow-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your array is sorted from smallest to largest, when you try to insert the, say, 15000th node using `insertPrep` (see the loop in `tree()`), you are going to **recursively** call `insert(AvlNode node, AvlNode newNode)` 15000 times.

This is due to the test in `insert`

```
  if (node.key > newNode.key){
     if(node.left!=null){node.left=insert(node.left , newNode);}
     else{node.left=newNode;}
  }
```

The recursions are too deep

Recursion is probably not your best choice to find the location in the tree and you should resort to a loop which will be more efficient anyway because you do not have to accumulate the frames between the calls.

Alternatively, use a language such as Scala that knows about tail recursion and automatically unfolds tail recursions to loops at compile time.

**EDIT**
The explanation for the Overflow is probably over simplistic. See comments below

Comment: I don't think it will be 15000, because this code rebalances the tree after each insert, so it would never end up traversing as many as 15000 nodes.  It would be interesting to see at what point the stack overflow actually occurs.

Comment: You are probably right: I have not really checked what the rebalancing does. The stack of the Overflow and inserting logging in the code, would certainly help. Yet IMHO traversing large trees with recursion is probably only looking good from an artistic/intellectual point of view :)

Comment: True.  It is hard to know from the information given whether there's actually a logic error in the code, or whether the stack is just getting overwhelmed by the volume of everything.  But definitely, with the volume of data that the OP is describing, she'd be better off with an iterative solution than a recursive one.

Comment: 30000 nodes should be ok for a balanced tree because the depth will should only be ln(30000), which is not that big. Provide re-balancing is done properly, which I think is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with re-balancing.

You are doing

```
AvlNode result = rebalance(node); 
adjustHeight(result);
```

which looks weird to me because you should adjust the height first then re-balance then adjust height again. Looks like re-balancing never happened because height is never updated; hence, your tree will be very high; hence, the stack overflow exception.

I am not 100% certain, but that looks like the problem. One sanity check you can do is to create, say, 100 nodes and check if your tree is balanced. If not, you didn't implement the balancing properly.

Comment: The height calculation is wrong, because leaf nodes and nulls both have height zero.  So the condition that checks whether a rebalance is required is the wrong one.  This is probably the problem, but I'm not sure how to prove it.